# Can the Cholesky factorization of $A$ be obtained from the Cholesky factoriztion of $P^TAP$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ is a symmetric, PD matrix, and let $P$ be a permutation matrix. Suppose that $LL^T$ is a Cholesky factorization of $P^TAP$. Is there a simple way to recover the Cholesky factorization of $A$?

My instinct is no. We have
$$P^TAP = LL^T \implies A = (PLP^T)(PLP^T)^T = L'L'^T.$$
However, $L'$ may not be lower-triangular anymore.

Comment: $PL$ permutes the rows of $L$ and $(PL)P^\top$ (inversely) permutes the columns of $PL\,.$ Try that with the first and last row (then column) to see that $PLP^\top$ is surely not  lower triangular when $L$ is sufficiently "fat".

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for the comment. I see that if $L$ has more than one column, and if it has a non-zero in the bottom left corner, then following your procedure yields a matrix with a non-zero in the top right corner, which is not lower triangular. So this particular method does not work. However, I am wondering if there is another method which works.

Comment: I think to get the Cholesky factorization of $A$ you have to do the Cholesky factorization of $A\,.$ The good new is that this algorithm is very fast so the question is only of some academical interest.

Comment: @KurtG. The issue is that even if $A$ is sparse, the Cholesky factors $L, L^T$ may be dense. However, it is possible to find a permutation matrix $P$ such that the Cholesky factorization of $P^TAP$ is sparse (this is called nested dissection). This is why I am wondering if we can recover the factorization. However, I just realized that the argument I just wrote demonstrates that the Cholesky factorization of $P^TAP$ is not necessarily a permutation of the Cholesky factorization of $A$, because if it were, then these factorizations would have the same sparsity.

Comment: That makes sense. To me $A$ is always a covariance or correlation matrix. Seems like $L$ becomes sparse when we reorder the random variables such that the highly correlated ones come first. Then $L$ is only non sparse in its upper left corner and therefore sparse. In the extreme other case we can achieve that $L$ is non sparse  in its lower region (this is probably the case when it is most non sparse). Are there cases when these things matter in runtime optimzation for example?

Comment: @KurtG. I am not sure about runtime, but having sparse matrices should reduce the effect of floating point errors.